# How do I get values from a dynamically created android TableRow?

Tags: android, tablerow, android-tablelayout

I used the code below to create a `TableRow` with content dynamically. It works good but I wish to get the values in the `TableRow`. Here is the sample code (I got it from Google), it has two text values in the `TableRow`. When I click the `TableRow` at any position it gives the corresponding value in the `TableRow` (I wish something similar to a `ListView`).

**All_CustomsActivity.java**

```
public class All_CustomsActivity extends Activity {

    String companies[] = { "Google", "Windows", "iPhone", "Nokia", "Samsung",
            "Google", "Windows", "iPhone", "Nokia", "Samsung", "Google",
            "Windows", "iPhone", "Nokia", "Samsung" };
    String os[] = { "Android", "Mango", "iOS", "Symbian", "Bada", "Android",
            "Mango", "iOS", "Symbian", "Bada", "Android", "Mango", "iOS",
            "Symbian", "Bada" };

    TableLayout tl;
    TableRow tr;
    TableRow mTable = null;
    TextView companyTV, valueTV;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.maintable);
        // addHeaders();
        addData();

    }

    /** This function add the headers to the table **/
    public void addHeaders() {

        /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
        tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
        TextView companyTV = new TextView(this);
        companyTV.setText("Companies");
        companyTV.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        companyTV.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
        companyTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        companyTV.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 0);
        tr.addView(companyTV); // Adding textView to tablerow.

        /** Creating another textview **/
        TextView valueTV = new TextView(this);
        valueTV.setText("Operating Systems");
        valueTV.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        valueTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        valueTV.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 0);
        valueTV.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
        tr.addView(valueTV); // Adding textView to tablerow.

        // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        // we are adding two textviews for the divider because we have two
        // columns
        tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        /** Creating another textview **/
        TextView divider = new TextView(this);
        divider.setText("-----------------");
        divider.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        divider.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        divider.setPadding(5, 0, 0, 0);
        divider.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
        tr.addView(divider); // Adding textView to tablerow.

        TextView divider2 = new TextView(this);
        divider2.setText("-------------------------");
        divider2.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        divider2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        divider2.setPadding(5, 0, 0, 0);
        divider2.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
        tr.addView(divider2); // Adding textView to tablerow.

        // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }

    /** This function add the data to the table **/
    public void addData() {

        for (int i = 0; i < companies.length; i++) {
            /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
            tr = new TableRow(this);
            tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            // ImageView im = new ImageView(this);
            // im.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sample_image);
            // im.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            // LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            // tr.addView(im);
            /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
            companyTV = new TextView(this);
            companyTV.setText(companies[i]);
            companyTV.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            companyTV.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
            companyTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            companyTV.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            tr.addView(companyTV); // Adding textView to tablerow.

            /** Creating another textview **/
            valueTV = new TextView(this);
            valueTV.setText(os[i]);
            valueTV.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            valueTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            valueTV.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            valueTV.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
            tr.addView(valueTV); // Adding textView to tablerow.

            // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
            tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            // tr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            // public void onClick(View view) {
            // view.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
            // }
            // });
            //
            // tr.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            // public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // mTable = (TableRow) v; // assign selected TableRow gobally
            // openContextMenu(v);
            // return true;
            // }
            // });

        }
    }

    // @Override
    // public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
    // ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    // super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    // menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Do YourStuff");
    //
    // }
    //
    // @Override
    // public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // int ccount = (mTable).getChildCount();
    // String[] str = new String[ccount];
    // for (int i = 0; i < ccount; i++) {
    // TextView tv = (TextView) (((TableRow) mTable)).getChildAt(i);
    // str[i] = tv.getText().toString(); // set selected text data into the
    // // String array
    // }
    // Toast.makeText(All_CustomsActivity.this, Arrays.toString(str), 2)
    // .show();
    // return true;
    // }

}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/maintable"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="0,1" >
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

In the code above some lines are commented, these lines are what I already tried to get the row values but it failed. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I guess you're talking about getting those values on a `TableRow` click. If this is the case you could add a listener to your `TableRow` and use `getChildAt` to get a hold of the two `TextViews` and get the data:

```
//...
tr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View view) {
      TableRow t = (TableRow) view;
      TextView firstTextView = (TextView) t.getChildAt(0);
      TextView secondTextView = (TextView) t.getChildAt(1);
      String firstText = firstTextView.getText().toString();
      String secondText = secondTextView.getText().toString();
   }
});
//...
```

Answer (score 1):

To get data from textview first u need to identify its parent from that u need to get your textView child position then u can get data from it... Here is a sample

```
 String myText;
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {                          
   TableRow tablerow = (TableRow)v.getParent();
   TextView items = (TextView) tablerow.getChildAt(2);

   myText = items.getText().toString();
  }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 spinnerSelection.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { 

                        TableRow selectedRow = (TableRow)spinnerSelection.getParent();
                        int index = tableLayout.indexOfChild(selectedRow);
```

Here **index** is the selected row index value and you can call all the views under the parent row (selectedRow) like the below set of lines.

```
Button roomNo = (Button) selectedRow.getChildAt(0);
Spinner selectionA = (Spinner) selectedRow.getChildAt(1);
Spinner selectionB = (Spinner) selectedRow.getChildAt(2);
```

Happy Coding!!