# Getting data from TableLayout?

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

When I'm trying to get the values to calculate the total I'm unable to get the values, instead getting *android.widget.TableRow@4103c468*. How can I overcome this situation and more I need to pass those values to another `Activity`. My code:

```
public class ProvisionActivity extends Activity {

    private TableLayout mTable;
    private static int sCount = 0;
    Button btnAdd;
    String[] pnames = { "provision1", "provision2", "provision3", "provision4",
            "provision5" };
    String[] pprice = { "45", "85", "125", "15", "198" };
    StringBuffer xpenses;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableprovision);
        xpenses = new StringBuffer();
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                mTable.addView(addRow(pnames, pprice));

                for (int i = 0; i < mTable.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    mTable.getChildAt(i);

                    System.out.println("Table Row values are   "
                            + mTable.getChildAt(i));

                    xpenses = xpenses.append(mTable.getChildAt(i).toString());

                    System.out
                            .println("Expense Table Values Are After Storing it in a String variable "
                                    + xpenses);

                }
            }
        });

    }

    private TableRow addRow(String[] sname, final String[] sprice) {

        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setId(1000 + sCount);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        TableRow.LayoutParams blparams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(150, 35);
        final Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
        spinner.setLayoutParams(blparams);
        spinner.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        ArrayAdapter<String> xtypeadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, sname);

        spinner.setAdapter(xtypeadapter);
        tr.addView(spinner);
        TableRow.LayoutParams tlparams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(55,
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setLayoutParams(tlparams);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                textView.setText("  "
                        + sprice[spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()]);

            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }
        });
        tr.addView(textView);
        TableRow.LayoutParams blparams1 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        final Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setLayoutParams(blparams1);
        button.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        button.setText(" - ");
        button.setId(2000 + sCount);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mTable.removeView(findViewById(v.getId() - 1000));
            }
        });
        tr.addView(button);
        sCount++;
        return tr;

    }
}
```

> LAYOUT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="154dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
        android:text="Total"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableprovision"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="74dp" >
    </TableLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:text="Expenses "
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:text="Add" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: refer this previous post, i hope it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514097/how-to-get-values-from-a-dinamically-created-android-tablerow

Comment: @Aerrow As you observe in question when user added a row in that i'll get spinner and a textview and a button .then i have couple of things in the spinner from that user'll select his desired.Now i need to get the corresponding things values in my oncreate so by that i can calculate total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i solved the above issue in the below shown way.. with some modifications to the above code

```
public class ProvisionActivity extends Activity {

private TableLayout mTable;
private static int sCount = 0;
Button btnAdd, btntot;
TextView tot;
int sum = 0;
String[] pnames = { "provision1", "provision2", "provision3", "provision4",
        "provision5" };
String[] pprice = { "45", "85", "125", "15", "195" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableprovision);
    tot = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewsum);
    btntot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttontotal);

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mTable.addView(addRow(pnames, pprice));
        }
    });

    btntot.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            int total = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < mTable.getChildCount(); i++) {
                TableRow mRow = (TableRow) mTable.getChildAt(i);
                Spinner mspinner = (Spinner) mRow.getChildAt(0);
                TextView mTextView = (TextView) mRow.getChildAt(1);
                Log.i("mspinner", "" + mspinner.getSelectedItem());
                total = total
                        + Integer.parseInt(mTextView.getText().toString());
            }

            System.out.println("Sum of the provision are " + total);
            tot.setText("" + total);
        }

    });

}

private TableRow addRow(String[] sname, final String[] sprice) {

    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    tr.setId(1000 + sCount);
    tr.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    TableRow.LayoutParams blparams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(150, 35);
    final Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
    spinner.setLayoutParams(blparams);
    spinner.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    ArrayAdapter<String> xtypeadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, sname);

    spinner.setAdapter(xtypeadapter);
    tr.addView(spinner);
    TableRow.LayoutParams tlparams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(55,
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setLayoutParams(tlparams);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        private boolean flag = false;

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> spin, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            if (flag) {
                flag = true;
                return;
            }

            textView.setText(sprice[position]);

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });
    tr.addView(textView);
    TableRow.LayoutParams blparams1 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    final Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setLayoutParams(blparams1);
    button.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    button.setText(" - ");
    button.setId(2000 + sCount);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            sCount--;
            mTable.removeView(findViewById(v.getId() - 1000));

        }
    });
    tr.addView(button);
    sCount++;
    return tr;

}
}
```